# Windows 10 Bluetooth audio crackling with Soundcore Life Q10 headlines

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

Recently, I've been experiencing a very peculiar problem with my audio on Windows 10. When using my headphones (Soundcore Life Q10), certain songs have this weird crackling sound. I've tried several troubleshooting steps, and I don't think it's my headphones, since it only occurs on *some* songs, but not others. Sometimes, a song that had crackling the day before won't have it the next day.

I'm very confused about what's happening. Does anyone know what this is, and how I can fix it?

For a bit more context:

- I'm on a managed device. Run, most sound settings, and a lot of other very useful settings are unavailable. To what extent, I'm not sure.
- I'm using a Bluetooth audio device (Soundcore Life Q10). I have not tried to see if the issue persists with the aux cable yet
  I do have the headphones' bass-boosting features enabled (the "Bass UP" thing)
- I have the following services enabled for my headphones: "Audio Sink", "Remote Control", "Remotely Controllable Device", "SerialPort"
- I have no sound enhancements enabled (even Spatial Sound is disabled)
- Exclusive Mode is fully disabled

#### Thus far, I've tried the following:

- Re-paired my headphones. No effect.
- Used different speakers (wired). Crackling was gone
- Disabled Exclusive Mode. No effect.
- Reset my headphones. Worked for a few hours, then the crackling came back. Resets after this had no effect
- Tried a different media source (Groove instead of Spotify). No effect (same problem - some audio had the crackling, some didn't)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the Lenovo Yoga I was using before. I've since upgraded to a Lenovo Yoga L13 Gen2 and the issue has been resolved.

I'd suggest trying your headphones on a different device to see if that problem persists.